# SSIS - Continue further process , on processing multiple files, if any one of the file errored out

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

I've to load data from multiple files in to a table thorough for each loop container in SSIS. If any one of the file got error-ed out then the package stops execution.

Now, i've to move the error-ed file to a different path and continue to process the remaining files.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: There isn't a question. Can you please explicitly ask the question?

Comment: requirement:
Load the data into a table from flat file..

Comment: There are many many _many_ examples of this online. Why don't you google some, try them, and post back specific questions?

Answer (score 0):

Look at properties of containers and tasks.  There are settings to determine how you want to handle errors.  They can be ignored or stop execution of the package.

You can also look at constraints to use different paths depending on success or failure.

Lastly you can look at error handling via events.

Between those three topics you should be able to do whatever you want.  There is plenty of blogs, faqs and examples available online.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect arrows to different tasks you can right click and the arrow you drag and it will give you different options. One of the options on the arrows will be continue even on error.